# How to recreate table in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, alter, recreate, drop

I am sorry for my bad English. Okay? my problem is i need to recreate temporary table many times (more then 5). I need totally change structure of table. 
I try do it like this but i have errors

```
CREATE TABLE  #DeletedData (RoleName varchar(max),  [Description] varchar(max))
....
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DeletedData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DeletedData
CREATE TABLE  #DeletedData (RoleName varchar(max),  DependentRoleName varchar(max))
```

Comment: *i have errors* is a useless problem description unless you include information about what those *errors* are specifically.

Comment: this looks like syntax from SQL SERVER, is the question correct tagged

Answer (score 0):

IN mysql you would do

```
CREATE TABLE  `#DeletedData` (RoleName LONGTEXT,  Description LONGTEXT);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `#DeletedData`;     
CREATE TABLE  `#DeletedData` (RoleName LONGTEXT,  DependentRoleName LONGTEXT);
```

Your code works in SQL server, so there is no need to change anything